# Infinite double summation and linear summation: $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_{ij} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^i a_{j(i-j)} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Let $a_{ij}$ be an infinite double-indexed array of real numbers and $\sum_i \sum_j |a_{ij}| < +\infty$. Does this equation hold:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_{ij} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^i a_{j(i-j)}?
$$

**My progress:**

I have proved the situation where $a_{ij}$ are nonnegative, but I have no idea how to prove the general one. My progress is as follows:

Assume $a_{ij} \ge 0$.

$$
\sum_i^m \sum_j^i a_{j (i - j)} \le \sum_i^m \sum_j^m a_{ij} \le \sum_i^{2m} \sum_j^i a_{j (i - j)}.
$$

Let $m \to \infty$, we will get the desired equation.

---

Yet in the general situation, these inequalities listed above does not necessarily hold.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product

Comment: @kipf Cauchy product seems off topic here. @ HWC The answer is: yes, simply because $\{(j,i-j)\mid0\le j\le i\}=\{(j,k)\mid0\le j,k\}.$

Comment: An absolutely convergent (double) series can be rearranged at will, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2062609/42969